# Registering kmeans model as UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

Hi  I am trying to use Spark kmeans model to predict the cluster number. But when I register it and use it in SQL it gives me a

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
def findCluster(s:String):Int={
    model.predict(feautarize(s))
}
```

I am using the below

```
%sql select findCluster((text)) from tweets
```

The same works if i use it directly

```
findCluster("hello am vishnu")
```

output 1

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to reproduce the problem with a code you've provided. Assuming that `model` is `org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel` here is step by step solution

First lets import required libraries and set RNG seed:

```
import scala.util.Random
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

Random.setSeed(0L)
```

Generate random train set:

```
// Generate random training set
val trainData = sc.parallelize((1 to 1000).map { _ =>
    val off = if(Random.nextFloat > 0.5) 0.5 else -0.5
    Vectors.dense(Random.nextFloat + off, Random.nextFloat + off)
})
```

Run KMeans

```
// Train KMeans with 2 clusters

val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20

val clusters = KMeans.train(trainData, numClusters, numIterations)
```

Create UDF

```
// Create broadcast variable with model and prediction function 
val model = sc.broadcast(clusters)
def findCluster(v: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector):Int={
    model.value.predict(v)
}

// Register UDF
sqlContext.udf.register("findCluster", findCluster _)
```

Prepare test set

```
// Create test set
case class Coord(v: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)
val testData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize((1 to 100).map { _ =>
    val off = if(Random.nextFloat > 0.5) 0.5 else -0.5
    Coord(Vectors.dense(Random.nextFloat + off, Random.nextFloat + off))
}))

// Register test set df
testData.registerTempTable("testData")

// Check if it works
sqlContext.sql("SELECT findCluster(v) FROM testData").take(1)
```

Result:

```
res3: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1])
```

Comment: Hey Thanks , Its working now. The mistake was with the way I am using Zeppelin for it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. It could be useful if you provide some explanation as a separate answer in case someone encounters a similar problem in the future.